# How does one enable an app's data to be added to users' default sections?

Tags: facebook, collections

At https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#datatodefaultsections it says:

> There's a way to suggest people add your app's data to their section
>   directly. It's best described with an example. If you were rdio, you
>   could suggest adding rdio's music.listens data to the music section
>   like this:
>
> https://www.facebook.com/me/music?rdiomusic
>
> /me is the special shortcut that refers to the person, music is the
>   special section for music and the rdiomusic is rdio's app namespace.
>   (The app namespace can be found in the Basic tab of your app's
>   dashboard settings.)

This functionality does not appear to be turned on or available for all developers. When attempting to do the above URL structure with my own app and a section (movies, music, books), there was no opportunity to add it to those sections as described.

Why not? Is this functionality not yet live / available to all?

Comment: Have you checked this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#customprompt

Comment: Yes, that's the link at the top of my question.

Comment: I am suspicious that the link in the documentation is incorrect. That style of query string parameters is very uncommon. Instead of "music?rdiomusic" it is more likely that the correct style is something like "music?app=rdiomusic". However I cannot find another answer to this question.

I would recommend filing a "Documentation Bug" on the FB bug tool.

Comment: The link in your question is not longer functional. In fact, there is practically no information at all about Open Graph collections in the FB developer documentation anymore. Are you aware of any changes they made to this feature?